# R Shiny : opening popup from server side

Tags: r, shiny

I use the bsModal instruction from the ShinyBS package to open popup in my application.

I would like to use this popup for rendering several plots with plotly, depending on which input button I click on, but as I have to return the graph name between quotes, I don't succeed to do that.

This is a part of my UI code :

```
tabItem(tabName = "Tab 1",
    useShinyjs(),

      bsModal("modal_graph", textOutput("graph_title"), textOutput("graph_name"), size = "large",
      fluidRow(plotlyOutput("graph_df", height = 700))),
```

And a part of my Server :

```
observeEvent(input$btn_modal_graphCG,{

    graph_title <- paste("Housing class : ", CL1)
    output$graph_title <- renderText({graph_title})

    graph_name <- shQuote("btn_modal_graphCG")
    output$graph_name <- renderText({graph_name})
```

As you can see, the third argument of bsModal must be the name of the input modal button : "btn_modal_graphCG", so I suppose I have to send it with double quotes to Ui, but I don't succeed to do that.

Do you see how I can do it ?

Thank you very much for helping.

EDIT : I changed the post title, and I found how to do with the toggleModal command which opens a popup from server side :

In ui, just after the dashboardBody open line I add :

```
useShinyjs(),    
    bsModal("modal_graph", textOutput("graph_title"), "", size = "large",            
        fluidRow(              
          plotlyOutput("graph_df", height = graph_size)
) # end of fluidRow(

) # end of bsModal(
```

With an associated action button :

```
actionButton("btn_modal_graph_", "", width = 100, icon("bar-chart"), class = "btn_block", style = "color : #FFF ; background-color : #337ab7 ; border-color : #2e6da4")
```

And server side :

```
observeEvent(input$btn_modal_graph,{
             .........
             .........
             output$graph_df <- renderPlotly({
             .........
             .........
                      }) # end of renderPlotly

toggleModal(session, "modal_graph", "open")

}) # end of observeEvent
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: Hello SymbolixAu, sorry for the mistake, I have edited my post, thank you.

Comment: No, unfortunately, it does not work. I'm going to try with the "toggleModal" command which opens a popup from server side. Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: I would use `uiOutput("themodal")` in the ui, and in server, i would do `output$themodel<-renderUI({bsModal(...)})`. `textOutput` doesn't return just text, it returns text in a div.

Comment: Thank you very much waterling, I just found with the "toggleModal" command. Have a nice day.

Comment: Would be nice if you posted it as an answer yourself and marked it correct.

Comment: You're right Mike, I have edited my post and changed the title.